# Selenium With Firefox Cannot Access Webpage

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

My code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\gecko\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.out.println("Gecko Driver Found");
    driver =new FirefoxDriver();
    System.out.println("WebDriver Established");
    driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/sweatshirts");
    System.out.println("Connection Established");
}
}
```

Running this gives me `SessionNotCreatedException` when the program tries to establish the driver, which I'll dump at the bottom.  I'm just trying to make the program load a webpage right now, so any help would be great.

Console Output:

> Sep 30, 2016 10:26:37 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
>   1475288797965   addons.xpi  WARN    Error loading bootstrap.js for {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}: Module `resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/bootstrap.js` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/bootstrap.js (resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/require.js:24) JS Stack trace: make/require@require.js:24:12 < @bootstrap.js:10:23 < @XPIProvider.jsm:4339:1 < XPI_loadBootstrapScope@XPIProvider.jsm:4339:7 < XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4414:1 < addMetadata@XPIProvider.jsm:3334:1 < XPI_processFileChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3443:23 < XPI_checkForChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3604:34 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2092:25 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
>   1475288797965   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method install on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}: TypeError: this.bootstrapScopes[aAddon.id][aMethod] is not a function (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4442:8) JS Stack trace: XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4442:9 < addMetadata@XPIProvider.jsm:3334:1 < XPI_processFileChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3443:23 < XPI_checkForChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3604:34 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2092:25 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
>   Sep 30, 2016 10:26:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
>   1475288799084   addons.xpi  WARN    Error loading bootstrap.js for {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}: Module `resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/bootstrap.js` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/bootstrap.js (resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/require.js:24) JS Stack trace: make/require@require.js:24:12 < @bootstrap.js:10:23 < @XPIProvider.jsm:4339:1 < XPI_loadBootstrapScope@XPIProvider.jsm:4339:7 < XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4414:1 < addMetadata@XPIProvider.jsm:3334:1 < XPI_processFileChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3443:23 < XPI_checkForChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3604:34 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2092:25 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
>   1475288799085   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method install on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}: TypeError: this.bootstrapScopes[aAddon.id][aMethod] is not a function (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4442:8) JS Stack trace: XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4442:9 < addMetadata@XPIProvider.jsm:3334:1 < XPI_processFileChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3443:23 < XPI_checkForChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3604:34 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2092:25 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
>   Sep 30, 2016 10:26:40 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
>   1475288800182   addons.xpi  WARN    Error loading bootstrap.js for {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}: Module `resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/bootstrap.js` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/bootstrap.js (resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/require.js:24) JS Stack trace: make/require@require.js:24:12 < @bootstrap.js:10:23 < @XPIProvider.jsm:4339:1 < XPI_loadBootstrapScope@XPIProvider.jsm:4339:7 < XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4414:1 < addMetadata@XPIProvider.jsm:3334:1 < XPI_processFileChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3443:23 < XPI_checkForChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3604:34 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2092:25 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
>   1475288800183   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method install on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}: TypeError: this.bootstrapScopes[aAddon.id][aMethod] is not a function (resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4442:8) JS Stack trace: XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4442:9 < addMetadata@XPIProvider.jsm:3334:1 < XPI_processFileChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3443:23 < XPI_checkForChanges@XPIProvider.jsm:3604:34 < XPI_startup@XPIProvider.jsm:2092:25 < callProvider@AddonManager.jsm:208:12 < _startProvider@AddonManager.jsm:667:5 < AMI_startup@AddonManager.jsm:824:9 < AMP_startup@AddonManager.jsm:2402:5 < AMC_observe@addonManager.js:55:7
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
>   Build info: version: '3.0.0-beta4', revision: '3169782', time: '2016-09-29 10:29:23 -0700'
>   System info: host: [REDACTED], ip: [REDACTED], os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:80)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:235)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:230)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:226)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
>       at copDatBogo.SupremeAccesser.main(SupremeAccesser.java:11)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an edit made by Daniel Cheng I was able to gopogle the exception and diagnose the issue.

I reinstalled firefox, but did so to a new directory.  My final functioning code is as follows:

```
package copDatBogo;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
public class SupremeAccesser {



public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\gecko\\geckodriver.exe");
        File pathToBinary = new File("path to firefox.exe");
        FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
        FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        System.out.println("Gecko Driver Found");
        driver =new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, ffProfile);
        System.out.println("WebDriver Established");
        driver.get("URL");
        System.out.println("Connection Established");
    }
}
```

I apologize for my lackluster diagnostic skill and will comb the error messages more thoroughly in the future.